# How to apply driverless device into harmony v3

Tags: c, embedded, microchip, mplab-x

I would like to apply HM628128 and MX25L800 to File System of MPLAB® Harmony v3.
But, the file system (MEMORY driver) of harmony v3 with default condition can be only applicatable to RAM/ROM listed below.

1. AT24
2. AT25
3. AT25DF
4. SST26
5. NVM
6. RAM

[image]

Does anyone know the way such as code new driver and recode MEMEORY driver to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.